# Flex 4.6 Custom Sorting of list

Tags: apache-flex, list, sorting, collections, adobe

So my problem seems to be simple but for the love of god i cant figure it out. So i am asking for your help. I have a simple list in a mobile application containing shops. I want to short them by distance from the center of my map.

It seems like i need a custom sorting function but im not sure on whati have to do in it.

i am using

```
testDist.setLatLng(propertyList.selectedItem.lat,propertyList.selectedItem.lng);

dist.text=""+GeodesicCalculatorUtil.calculateGeodesicDistance(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.currentLatLng2,testDist,DistanceUnits.KILOMETERS)
```

to get the distance for a shop and i have to compare it with the next one. however i cant figure out how to do it in the comparing function. I would be glad if anyone can help me.

Comment: What is your data type for the list? An ArrayCollection? What have you tried to do to sort it?  Have you read these docs: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=about_dataproviders_2.html

Comment: i get my data from a php service and my list's dataprovider is defined as <s:AsyncListView list="{getAllMarkersResult.lastResult}"/> from there iam using the lat and lng to get the distance which i need to use for sorting.

Comment: It doesn't look like an AsyncListView has any sorting capabilities like an ArrayCollection or XMLListCollection would.  You may consider switching; or sorting your data on the server side before retrieving it.

Comment: it actually works just fine if a just use a field from the database to do the sorting. my problem is that i cant figure out how to use the custom functions to sort the list. 

For example i can sort the list using the lat from the database. However i want to first do some calculations before doing that like lat+1 .

Comment: You don't sort a List class in Flex, as it is just a display class.  You sort a List's dataProvider based on the type of data it is.  An ArrayCollection or XMLListCollection provide built in sorting functionalities as I linked to above.  An ASyncListView does not.  To perform calculations or other processing on data--in a Collection class--you can use a sortCompareFunction.

Comment: you are right you can only sort the dataprovider which in this case is getall.lastresult (lastresult is a collection with all the returned data). after all day researching and reading examples i managed to work it out.

Comment: I'll also add that an ASyncListView is not a Flex Collection class; so I'm confused as to what was going on.Please be sure to post your solution as a formal answer to this question.

Comment: when using services to get data from a database, the "lastresult" collection is available which can be used as a dataprovider for lists datagrids etc. as can be seen on my solution i did a sorting on the lastresult collection using the calculated distance of pois from the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this seems to be a common problem for people using MapQuest as their mapping system, i provide my solution for sorting the custom POIs by distance to any list. This is a solution for mobile applications and this is the reason im using lists over datagrid.

```
protected function sort_clickHandler():void
            {               

                var dataSortField:SortField = new SortField();
                dataSortField.numeric = true;

                /* Create the Sort object and add the SortField object created earlier to the array of fields to sort on. */
                var numericDataSort:Sort = new Sort();

                numericDataSort.compareFunction=sortFunction;

                /* Set the ArrayCollection object's sort property to our custom sort, and refresh the ArrayCollection. */
                getAllMarkersResult.lastResult.sort = numericDataSort;
                getAllMarkersResult.lastResult.refresh();
            }

            private function sortFunction(a:Object, b:Object, array:Array = null):int
            {

                var aPoi:LatLng = new LatLng(a.lat,a.lng);
                var bPoi:LatLng = new LatLng(b.lat,b.lng);

                var i:Number=GeodesicCalculatorUtil.calculateGeodesicDistance(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.currentLatLng2,aPoi,DistanceUnits.KILOMETERS);
                var j:Number=GeodesicCalculatorUtil.calculateGeodesicDistance(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.currentLatLng2,bPoi,DistanceUnits.KILOMETERS);


                return ObjectUtil.numericCompare(i, j);


            }
```